# Android - Background Image Animation in Loop

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to animate an image (used as background image but it doesn't really matter) in such a way that it will move from left to right but in a cyclic way.
For example, if the image size is exactly as the view size, once the most right column of pixels exceeded the right edge, it will appear on the most left side of the view.

I've thought of several ways of doing it but all of them sounds too complicated to me and I'm sure there is a more "core" way to do that.

Thanks,
Lior.

Comment: `For example, if the image size is exactly as the view size, once the most right column of pixels exceeded the right edge, it will appear on the most right side of the view.`  Don't you mean `, it will appear on the most left side of the view.`?

Comment: @techiServices:Yep, that a lot

Comment: I edited the question for you to reflect that.

Comment: I can't think of a simple way of getting the `View` to behave as if it were a cylinder, however I am intrigued as to how it can be done so I will have a good think ;).  Comment on ways you have thought of please.

Comment: @techiServices See slayton's answer below, that's similar to kind of ideas I've thought of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use `canvas.drawBitmap(sourceRectangle,outputRectangle,null)` to cut a part from a strip bitmap background?  This is a similar method that is used to animate a bitmap, but you would add one pixel to the sourceRectangle's left and right values until it hits the edge of the background strip.

Comment: I wanted to avoid using surfaces but I guess I don't have any other option. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the `Bitmap` and the `ImageView` are the exact same size in pixels you can manually move the pixels around however you want.

```
int pixels[];
bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
shiftPixels(pixels, width, height);
bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.setWidth());
```

In `shiftPixels` simply create a copy of the original bitmap but when copying the pixels apply a linear shift to the pixels.  Something like this (un-tested pseudo-code);

```
void shiftPixels(int inPixels[], int bitmapHeight, int nPixHorizShift)
{

    int shift = bitmapHeight * nPixHorizShift;
    int outPixels[inPixels.size()];

    for i = 1:pixels.size()
       outPixels[(i + shift) % outPixels.size()] = inPixels[i];

    inPixels = outPixels;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's one of ideas I've thought of, I'm afraid it will cause some performance hit. I'll give it a try and update.

Comment: Another simple option is to simply have 2 bitmaps and to draw both of them. Start with Bitmap1 to the left of the view and bitmap 2 filling the view, each frame shift the two bitmaps to the right

Comment: @LiorOhana see my new comment