# Moving Background Android

Tags: java, android, loops, background

I am creating an android game with a moving bitmap background.  The background is supposed to be of a simple picture of space that moves for an infinite amount of time (it will loop).  I have no idea how to do this, and any help would be appreciated.

By the way, I am using a main class that extends GameView and implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, and I already have a game loop thread.

Thanks!

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641951/android-background-image-animation-in-loop

Answer (score 0):

```
    super.onDraw(c);
    bgx = bgx - 5;
    int newFarX = background.getWidth() - (-bgx);
    // if we have scrolled all the way, reset to start
    if (newFarX <= 0) {
        bgx = 0;
        // only need one draw
        c.drawBitmap(background, bgx + 10, 100, null);
    } else {
        // need to draw original and wrap
        c.drawBitmap(background, bgx + 10, 100, null);
        c.drawBitmap(background, newFarX, 100, null);
        // bgr.setPixel(0, background.getWidth(), (Integer) null);
        c.drawBitmap(bgr, bgx + 10, 100, null);
        c.drawBitmap(bgr, newFarX, 100, null);
    }
    // c.drawBitmap(jump, 100, 400, null);
    // objectSprite.setPosition(x, y);
    objectSprite.paint(c);
    // c.drawBitmap(canv1, 0, 200, null);

    objectSprite.nextFrame();
    invalidate();
```